# Retain decimal places in toString

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, rounding, tostring

Is there a way to make the resulting string from a 'double.toString()' contain the exact value of the double?

for example

```
double d = 123.0   ->   toString() will be "123"
```

I've found a little bit of a solution in using the custom format `.toString("#.0")` but if I want to add any more decimal places I'm back to where I started

```
double d = 123.00   ->  toString("#.0") will be 123.0
double d = 123.0    -> toString("#.00") will be 123.00
```

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I've got custom text boxes that must use a different value to the one thats actually displayed and when trying to enter your own value into this text box the textbox is ignoring your text when you try to enter zero in decimal places. Therefore I need the `toString` value to equal the exact value of the `double` so this number can be entered properly.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the resulting string from a 'double.toString()' contain the exact value of the double?

It *does* contain the exact value of a `double` - but a `double` doesn't store any difference between 123, and 123.0 and 123.00.

`decimal` stores the difference, however - and is far more appropriate if you care about exact decimal digits anyway.

On the other hand, it sounds like *actually* you're doing the comparison in the wrong place:

> The reason I'm trying to do this is because I've got custom text boxes that must use a different value to the one thats actually displayed and when trying to enter your own value into this text box the textbox is ignoring your text when you try to enter zero in decimal places.

Don't compare the *string* values - parse the value (to either `decimal` or `double`) and then compare the parsed values.

This will also prevent problems with *leading* zeroes, where "0123" and "123" represent the same value, but are different strings.

Comment: man, you're fast ;) Is posting on stackoverflow your full time job?

Comment: +1 for the last piece of info. Didn't know that decimal knew the difference between the number of digits suplied

Comment: @animaonline his fulltime job doesn't even involve C#

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.. I wasn't trying to compare the values, I was trying to write the value into the textbox. Very useful insight though! (Edit: changing to decimal solved problem)